# wp_redirect loop when using geoip

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting an endless redirect loop that results in a too many redirects error when trying to redirect a user when detecting a specific country.

What I'm trying to achieve is to add to the end of the request url a param that is the language and redirect to the same page that will result in them viewing the site in their own language.

Here's what I've done:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'geoip_redirect');
function geoip_redirect()
{
    if (function_exists('geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip')) {

         $user_info = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
         $country_code = $user_info->country->isoCode;
         $request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?lang=he';
         $url = get_site_url(null, $request_url);

         if ($country_code == 'IL') {
             wp_redirect($url);
             exit();
         }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition like checking for the lang parameter before executing the code otherwise It will keep executing forever.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'geoip_redirect');
function geoip_redirect()
{
    if (function_exists('geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip')) {
         if ( ! isset( $_GET['lang'] ) ) {
            $user_info = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
            $country_code = $user_info->country->isoCode;
            $request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?lang=he';
            $url = get_site_url(null, $request_url);

            if ($country_code == 'IL') {
               wp_redirect($url);
               exit();
            }
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: There is a condition, the redirect is only executed when the user is identified from said country

Comment: oh, sorry didn't see that, well you need to check "geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip()"  function. It seems that It keeps returning the same value. Try to echo $country_code; die(); after the $country_code  and check what you get